# Android - determine fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which has one MainActivity and two Fragments. These fragments send argument to MainActivity this way:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putLong("id",id);
sf.setArguments(args);
```

And then MainActivity takes argument in `onCreate()` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    private long wayId = getArguments().getLong("id");
}
```

How can I determine which fragment sent this argument to MainActivity ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another argument into the bundle like the tag of the fragment.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putLong("id",id);
args.putString("fragmentTag", fragmentTag);
sf.setArguments(args);
```

and retrive the tag in your onCreate()

Comment: I know it, but is there a way to use something like getClass ?

Comment: yes you can use this.getClass() and if the name of the fragment class is unique you can use that as identifier.

Comment: Or you can use fragment.getTag() but you have to assign the tag during the creation of the fragment, so like fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "your_tag");

Answer (score 1):

You can define a separate inrterface for every fragment

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    public static interface FragmentAInterface {
        void doSomething(String data);
    }
}
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    public static interface FragmentBInterface {
        void doSomething(String data);
    }
}
```

And then in your activity:

```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.FragmentAInterface, FragmentB.FragmentBInterface{

    @Override
    public void doSomething(String data) {
        //Guaranteed to come from Fragment A
    }

    @Override
    public void doOtherThing(String data) {
        //Guaranteed to come from Fragment B
    }
}
```